# Statements after await next(context) is not executed in ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I have created a custom middleware and added a statements before and after the `await next(context)` method call.

If there is no middleware after my custom middleware, then the statements after `next(context)` also not executed.

But if there is a middleware, then the statements after `next(context)` are executed.

Can you please explain why this difference? Thank you in advance

This is my code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyMiddleware>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseMyMiddleware();
 
/*
 * When the below middleware is enabled, statements after next(context) is executed
 * when the below middleware is disabled, statements after next(context) is not executed
 */
//app.Run(async (context) =>
//{
//    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from run method\n");
//});
 
app.Run();
 
public class MyMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world from custom middle ware\n");
        await next(context);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from My Middleware ends\n");
    }
}
 
public static class MyMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        return app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know its not being executed? Can you check with console.writeline and the debugger?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev, Yes when I execute the statements without the second middleware, the browser output will only show the statements before the await next(context) method in first middleware only, but once the second middleware is added then the statements are shown in browser output

Comment: because you've called Response.WriteAsync before get into your handler,when your handler want to write the response,it would found the response has started

Answer (score 0):

> If there is no middleware after my custom middleware, then the statements after next(context) also not executed.

They are not just "not executed" they should be interrupted by exception because you have started writing the response and there are multiple actions which are not permitted when response has started (like setting status or adding headers) due to the structure of HTTP protocol messages. And one of the default middlewares invoked later down the pipeline will try to do something which is not allowed.

> When the below middleware is enabled statements after next(context) is executed

Because [`RunExtensions.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-7.0) adds so called short-circuiting or terminating middleware, i.e. it does not perform call similar to `await next(context);` so the subsequent default middlewares will not try to add headers or set response status code.

This is described at length in the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) doc.

P.S.

Actually I was not able to get the behavior you have described in comments - browser does not show me anything in case there is no terminating middleware, maybe version/settings depended though.